# Sessions nodejs with socket.io

Tags: node.js

I need to do sessions with nodejs, but using socket.io ..

I have this functional code, which works with the get method

```js
var express = require('express')
var session = require('express-session')
var app = express()
app.use(session({ 
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { maxAge: 28800000 }}))
 

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var sess = req.session
  if (sess.views) {
    sess.views++
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
    res.write('<p>views: ' + sess.views + '</p>')
    res.end()
    console.log(sess.views)
  } else {
    sess.views = 1
    res.end('welcome to the session demo. refresh!')
    console.log(sess.views)
  }
})
 
console.log('Server iniciado y operando!')
app.listen(3000)
```

But I need sessions using this method

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);


app.use(express.static('client'));

var messages = [{
 id: 1,
 text: 'Bienvenido al chat privado de Socket y Node de Luis Zurita',
 nickname: 'BELICOFSA dice:'
}];

io.on('connection', function(socket){
 console.log("El equipo con IP: "+socket.handshake.address+" se ha conectado...");
 socket.emit('caja-chat', messages);
 socket.on('add-message', function(data){
  messages.push(data);
  io.sockets.emit('caja-chat', messages);
 });

});

server.listen(3000, function(){
 console.log('Servidor esta Funcionando en http://localhost:6677'); 
});
```

What I have done best is this, but it does not work as code 1
can you help me?

```js
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var ios = require('socket.io-express-session');
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var Session = require('express-session');
var session = Session({
 secret: 'sdfgf',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { maxAge: 100000 }
});

 
var messages = [{
 id: 1,
 text: 'Bienvenido al chat privado de Socket y Node de Luis Zurita',
 nickname: 'BELICOFSA dice:'
}];

server.listen(3000, function(){
 console.log('Servidor esta Funcionando en http://localhost:6677'); 
});

 io.use(ios(session));
 app.use(express.static('client'));

 io.on('connection', function(socket){
 socket.handshake.session.save;
 var sess = socket.handshake.session;
 if (sess.views) {
    sess.views++
  } else {
    sess.views = 1
  }
 console.log(sess);
 socket.emit('caja-chat', messages);
 socket.on('add-message', function(data){
  messages.push(data);
  io.sockets.emit('caja-chat', messages);
 });
 });
```